# Getting error "Adding a value to a date column throws an overflown column" on a field not showing up when I do a select *

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query which is throwing an error

> Adding a value to a date column throws an overflown column

on this expression:

```
DATEADD(M, 1, NEXTDATE)
```

Now when I remove that column and do a `select *` in that query, I don't get any `NEXTDATE` which is invalid; all are valid dates. But table from which Nextdate column is sourced does has some dates with 12/31/9999. Now when I put a extra where condition as `year(NEXTDATE) != 9999`, it works fine.

So I believe it's trying to add 1 month to 12/31/9999 date and throwing that error. But I don't see that date with 9999 year when I do a `select *` over the table.

My question is when I do a simple `select *` why don't I see the date 12/31/9999 but putting the extra where condition solves the issue.

Comment: Try `select * from yourtable where year(nextdate) = 9999` to find the problems.  Could also, I suppose, be NULL related.

Comment: yes I tried that it does not return anything. I dont think Nulls have an issue with dateadd function

Comment: What is the datatype of `NEXTDATE`?

Comment: data type is date

Answer (score 0):

The value is there.  You have just missed it.

What does this return?

```
select max(nextdate)
from t;
```

Note:  It is possible that the value is actually filtered out by the query logic, but that the SQL optimizer decides to evaluate the expression even on filtered-out rows.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - Max returns a date from 2020. The note you mentioned is exactly my guess here. I had spent 5-6 hrs to figure out whats going on in the query

Comment: @JatinGang . . . Are you selecting from a view?